# Finding a guaranteed consequent of a satisfiable sentence

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

#### Let A = ∀x∀y(P(x,y)). A is satisfiable. Find any B such that it isn't a tautology and is a consequent of A.

Now if I understand it correctly, then a correct and somewhat trivial solution to this would be any sentence logically equal to A. For example neg(∃x∃y(neg(P(x,y))).

Is there anything else, or is this the only simple solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, there are statements that are weaker than $A$ which follow from it.  For example $\forall x \exists y (P(x,y))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about **reflexivity** - $\forall x (P(x, x))$?

Similarly, **transitivity** $\forall x\forall y\forall z(P(x, y)\wedge P(y, z)\implies P(x, z))$ and **symmetry** $\forall x\forall y(P(x, y)\implies P(y, x))$. And there are lots of others . . .

Comment: I can see that these do indeed work, thanks! I've noticed that these three are the key properties of an equivalence relation, although I'm slightly confused about what this has to do with A. What reasoning has made you come up with these?

Comment: @P.Lance They are properties which are (i) interesting, and (ii) only involve universal quantifiers and only positive instances of $P$ in the conclusion of any implication (e.g. not of the form "$...\implies \neg P(x, y)$"), which guarantees that they'll be true if $P$ always holds. (The sort of reasoning in (ii) becomes more natural as you go through logic; it also crops up in e.g. universal algebra.)

Answer (score 1):

Other consequents are $\exists x\exists y(P(x, y))$ if you don't allow empty domain structures in your semantics (as usual). Or you could add things infinitely: $\forall x\forall y(P(x,y))\vee\varphi$ for all $\varphi$ actually.